# Combined SQL Queries that return large results

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, join

I have a requirement to collect data from a mysql db to enable us to send out promotional emails to clients who have not been active for a given number of days, but only those who have never registered their promo points with us. The database is rather large, with in excess of 50,000 customers and the query to check for customer_id of those who haven't registered points takes over an hour to process alone.
So i figured that if i narrow it down to the customers who haven't logged in within a given time, and then run a search on only those customer_id's it would be faster. However, my attempt at combining the two queries was a total failure, returning "Operand should contain 1 column(s)" error.

Is it even possible to achieve given the data i need to receive on the query.

First query that takes 1hr:

```
SELECT c.customers_id
FROM customers c 
LEFT JOIN codes_redeem_history pc 
ON pc.customer_id=c.customers_id
WHERE pc.customer_id IS NULL
```

Second query for customers within given time:

```
SELECT ci.customers_info_date_of_last_logon, ci.customers_info_id, c.customers_email_address, c.customers_lastname, c.customers_firstname 
FROM customers c, customers_info ci 
WHERE c.customers_id = ci.customers_info_id 
GROUP BY c.customers_email_address 
HAVING max(ci.customers_info_date_of_last_logon) <= subdate(now(),INTERVAL 30 DAY) 
ORDER BY c.customers_lastname, c.customers_firstname ASC
```

How i tried, and failed to combine them:

```
SELECT c.customers_id
FROM customers c 
LEFT JOIN codes_redeem_history pc 
ON pc.customer_id=c.customers_id
WHERE pc.customer_id IS NULL
AND c.customers_id
IN
(Select ci.customers_info_date_of_last_logon, ci.customers_info_id, c.customers_email_address, c.customers_lastname, c.customers_firstname 
FROM customers c, customers_info ci 
WHERE c.customers_id = ci.customers_info_id 
GROUP BY c.customers_email_address 
HAVING max(ci.customers_info_date_of_last_logon) <= subdate(now(),INTERVAL 30 DAY) 
ORDER BY c.customers_lastname, c.customers_firstname ASC)
```

I can see from the error message that it won't allow such a complex query in the IN(SELECT )
part of the query, but i'm at a loss as to how to rearrange it, or if it's even feasible.

Any advice from you SQL Gurus?

Thanks

Following a slight change of requirements, i could do with a little more help on this.

Further to the earlier answer, i tried to change the query slightly to allow selection of time span, rather than it be fixed at 30 days. I used HAVING MAX( ci.customers_info_date_of_last_logon ) >= '" . $ndate . "' with $ndate being a var that holds the date required. Obviously it didn't work as a date isn't the same as 30 DAYS. I don't seem to be able to use a WHERE condition in place of HAVING MAX. Any solutions?

Comment: Your subquery inside IN() function returns multiple columns; you need to modify it to return only one column.

Comment: Would be nice to have the "explain" of the queries... It's weird that your first query takes so long, do you have indexes?

Comment: @m4573r No, there was no indexes and the codes_redeem_history table contains 400210 rows, hence it being so slow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why the first query takes too long to complete is, *I am almost sure of it*, because you lack index on the columns that defines their relationship, alter the table by executing the following line,

```
ALTER TABLE codes_redeem_history ADD INDEX (customer_id);
ALTER TABLE customers ADD INDEX (customers_id);
ALTER TABLE customers_info ADD INDEX (customers_info_id);
```

full query,

```
SELECT  c.customers_id
FROM    customers c 
        LEFT JOIN codes_redeem_history pc 
        ON pc.customer_id=c.customers_id
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            Select  c.customers_id 
            FROM    customers c 
                    INNER JOIN customers_info ci
                        ON c.customers_id = ci.customers_info_id 
            GROUP   BY c.customers_email_address 
            HAVING  MAX(ci.customers_info_date_of_last_logon) <= subdate(now(),INTERVAL 30 DAY)
        ) d ON c.customers_id = d.customers_id
WHERE   pc.customer_id IS NULL AND 
        d.customers_id IS NOT NULL
```

**UPDATE 1**

```
SELECT  c.customers_id
FROM    customers c 
        INNER JOIN customers_info ci
            ON c.customers_id = ci.customers_info_id 
        LEFT JOIN codes_redeem_history pc 
            ON c.customers_id = pc.customer_id
WHERE   pc.customer_id IS NULL
GROUP   BY c.customers_email_address 
HAVING  MAX(ci.customers_info_date_of_last_logon) <= subdate(now(),INTERVAL 30 DAY)
```

Comment: You sir, are an absolute diamond. The addition of INDEX made a huge difference 0.0006 secs to run the first part of the query now!But, the full sql returns "check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'd ON c.customers_id = d.customers_id WHERE pc.customer_id IS NULL AND ' at line 13"

Comment: oh sorry for the type, i missed the `)`. it should be `subdate(now(),INTERVAL 30 DAY)`

Comment: I would i flip the two queries around now so that the SELECT c.customers_id
FROM customers c 
LEFT JOIN codes_redeem_history pc 
ON pc.customer_id=c.customers_id
WHERE pc.customer_id IS NULL part filtered the results of the original second query?

Comment: Fantastic. Answer accepted and +1. Total query time 0.0037 seconds. Perfect answer

Comment: see how powerful indexes are.. but don't abuse them (*add them as long as you want*) as it will cause you to slowly do `inserts, updates, and deletes`...

Comment: I need to change this slightly. Main question appended. Could you take a look please?? Thanks in advance

Comment: can you further explain this line, *"..Obviously it didn't work as a date isn't the same as 30 DAYS."*, or you can open anopther question regarding this problem.

Comment: I'll open a new question. It's only fair you get the +1 and accept if you help :)